# CheckBox set ReadOnly but still clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, checkbox, data-binding

I've searched and tried many different things and can't find anything that works. I have two columns in a GridView that are CheckBoxes. The rows are of values that can be set to test the device connected.

Column one is saying if the row contains the default value and is bound to the value from the database whether or not it's checked. This can't be changed by the user. I've set the IsEnabled="false".

Column two allows the user to select a custom value other than the default value. I would love to have it so the row with the default value doesn't have this checkbox. Can't figure out how to make it invisible. So I bind the IsEnabled to a bool in the ViewModel that is set in the code behind based on if it's a default value or not before adding it to the ObservableCollection used for the ListView that holds this GridView. Yet the user can still click on this checkbox in the Default Value's row and it will change to show it was checked. I don't want that either.

I remember in WinForms there was a way to make the CheckBox completely ReadOnly but I could still manipulate its checked state in code. I can't seem to do that with WPF. Help!

XAML:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lsvThresholdDefaultValue" Header="Default" Width="50">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbxDefaultValue" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding DefaultValue}" 
                      IsEnabled="False"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn x:Name="lsvThresholdCustomValue" Header="Use This" Width="55">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbxUseThis" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding UseThisValue}" 
                      IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding AllowUse}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Code Behind:

```
if (oneThreshold.DefaultValue)
{
    oneThreshold.AllowUse = false;
}
else
{
    oneThreshold.AllowUse = true;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Here is what the answer is that I got from my coworker (which is what I really wanted to do anyway).

At the top added (maintenance is my namespace):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <maintenance:InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter 
                 x:Key="InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Then on the checkbox, I replaced IsEnabled with Visibility:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxUseThis" 
      IsChecked="{Binding UseThisValue}" IsHitTestVisible="False" 
      Visibility="{Binding AllowUse, Converter={StaticResource 
         BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Then to make the box NOT appear on the default value row, I added Visibility:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="cbxDefaultValue" 
      IsChecked="{Binding DefaultValue}" IsEnabled="False"
      Visibility="{Binding AllowUse, Converter={StaticResource 
           InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

The Inverse... was some code he wrote since there is no negate on BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Comment: Is the code you list as 'code behind' part of the code behind or part of the class for the objects you are binding to the grid? It would need to be part of the class for the objects you are binding to the grid since the {Binding AlllowUse} binds to a property of the object in the grid, not the code behind for your view. Also, the class for the objects you bind to the grid needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, does your class for the objects being bound to the grid implement that interface?

Comment: It's part of the actual code behind. It's while creating the ObservableCollection. I pull from the database all entries for this set of Thresholds then check the DefaultValue and determine if I allow it to be an option to be used in the test. I do use INotifyPropertyChanged in the class.